# dynamically creating image watermark

Tags: php, watermark

I want to add a watermark to all images in a directory dynamically using php and .htaccess. The following php code is giving me an error at line 6 saying 'Undefined index: i." All my images are .gif as well as .png and .jpeg.

```
<?php 

    $basedir="C:/vhosts/phpcs5/images/product_images"; 
    $watermarkimage="PreviewWatermark.png"; 

    $file=basename($_GET['i']); 

    $image = $basedir."/".$file; 
    $watermark = $basedir."/".$watermarkimage; 

    $im = imagecreatefrompng($watermark); 

    $ext = substr($image, -3); 

    if (strtolower($ext) == "gif") { 
    if (!$im2 = imagecreatefromgif($image)) { 
    echo "Error opening $image!"; exit; 
    } 
    } else if(strtolower($ext) == "jpg") { 
    if (!$im2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($image)) { 
    echo "Error opening $image!"; exit; 
    } 
    } else if(strtolower($ext) == "png") { 
    if (!$im2 = imagecreatefrompng($image)) { 
    echo "Error opening $image!"; exit; 
    } 
    } else {
     die; 
     } 
     imagefilledrectangle($im2, 0  , (imagesy($im2))-(imagesy($im)) , imagesx($im2)  , imagesy($im2) ,  imagecolorallocatealpha($im2, 0, 0, 0, 100) ); imagecopy($im2, $im, (imagesx($im2)-(imagesx($im))), (imagesy($im2))-(imagesy($im)), 0, 0, imagesx($im), imagesy($im)); 

     $last_modified = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T', filemtime ($image)); 

     header("Last-Modified: $last_modified"); 
     header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); 
     imagejpeg($im2,NULL,95); 
     imagedestroy($im); 
     imagedestroy($im2); 


?>
```

Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^([^thumb].*\.[jJ].*)$ phpcs5/images/product_images/w.php?i=$1 [L]
```

Comment: How do you call the script? Put a `print_r($_GET)` in the first line. What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your rewrite rule. You are going to match anything that doesn't start with t, h, u, m, or b. Without a better understanding of exactly what you want your rewrite rule to do, I can't really offer any additional assistance.

However, I'm guessing you want to rewrite anything not beginning with the word thumb, with an extension beginning with a j. (e.g. thumbfoo.jpg would not rewrite, but myimage.jpg would)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^thumb.*\.[jJ].*$
RewriteRule !(.*) /phpcs5/images/product_images/w.php?i=$1 [L]
```